# Radio Button Label Positioning

Tags: html, css, position

I need to place the label text to left and the radio button to the right side of the `div`.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/mK3DV/3/

Also when I check the result in code, the `radio checked` image size varies. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated fiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mK3DV/10/

Credit goes to rickyduck

Answer (score 0):

Give **padding** for your needs.

```
input[type="radio"] + label
{
    background: url(http://manual.evolvesystems.ws/img/check_icon.jpg) right center no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px; 
    width: 23px;
    height: 25px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:xx xx xx xx;
}
```